# Community bumping [status-completed] on meta.SU?

Tags: support

I don't think that it is right that the community user is bumping [status-completed] questions.

What do you think?

What about the other status tags?

Comment: @Sathya I don't see the `[support]` request here. It feels like a bug, and it was originally tagged as such. It's still more of a feature request than a support question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the questions have no accepted answer, they fall within the set of questions to be bumped. Even if an item is tagged completed, if no answer had been accepted, it is considered an active and open question. This happens a lot when users do not come back to follow up, or do not agree that it is completed to their satisfaction.

We are discussing with Jeff reducing the questions bumped on Meta as a whole, since the site does not generate a lot of traffic.

A more detailed explanation of how it works can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped/48579#48579)