# Community Voting System to accept answers not accepted by the OP

Tags: feature-request, users, voting, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community bumping [status-completed] on meta.SU?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1305/community-bumping-status-completed-on-meta-su)

I have noticed a lot of questions that are answered correctly and abandoned by the OP (i.e. they are not marked as accepted by the OP)

Can we have a voting system, where users above a particular reputation *(say 1000-2000 or whatever suitable)* can vote to accept such answers, maybe with a reason as to why they think that it would be the correct resolution the that particular problem.

I'm just thinking out loud here, we can add to this suggestion if wanted.

Comment: This request actually belongs on the site-wide [Stack Exchange engine meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).  However, it has already been [asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8600/94928) a [couple of times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3669/94928).

Comment: damn.. I searched this site for this question, I asked as it didn't exist. Didn't realize it was already out there and debated upon. No purpose on this staying as an open question then I vote to close this question. Thanks for pointing this out @heavyd

Comment: I am unable to vote to close this question (because the vote to close button is greyed out when I paste any of the above url's in the box) can a moderator please do so.

Comment: Related [Community bumping \[status-completed\] on meta.SU?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1305/community-bumping-status-completed-on-meta-su)