# Viewing change history to questions on superuser.com

Tags: support, editing, review

#### Question

As a regular user (i.e. not the OP or subsequent editor), is it possible to see what changes were made to a question (or one of its answers) on https://superuser.com?

#### Example

In a search for an answer to one of my own questions, I came across [this question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1315798/export-registry-key-to-csv)...

[image: superuser.com/questions/1315798, Red Modified 7 days ago, Green: timestamps (all from 2018)]

**RED** = Recent modified tagline (7 days ago)
**GREEN** = Question, editing, commenting timestamps (all from 2018)

---

I saw that it was asked a long time ago (nearly 5 years) and so assumed it was likely dead, however I also noticed it was just edited just a few days ago so I looked around the page to see what had been changed (hoping there was a recently-added answer or comment that would help me out on my own quest), however as I checked through I realised that **every timestamp** that I could see was from 2018, and there was no evidence of **any** recent changes at all (not even a new comment) for the past ~5 years or so

So this got me to wonder...

- Assuming there was some change in the past week, **what was it?**\
- **Is there a "version history"** (or something similar) where I could go and see what changed on a question?

#### Context

FYI: This isn't just mere curiosity or me trying to be nosy, I was potentially thinking of editing / otherwise contributing to the question and if it has some recent activity (e.g. was recently edited) then this would make it more likely for me spend some time on this, whereas if no-one has had any interest on adding to or updating this question in 5 years, I am more likely to prioritise my time on something else.

Comment: Yes; There [is](https://meta.superuser.com/posts/14951/revisions).

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the revision history by clicking the "edited Apr 20, 2018 at 19:12" link:

[image]

which goes to [the revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1315798/revisions).

Most of the recent history is simply it being [bumped by community](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1305/community-bumping-status-completed-on-meta-su).